# Firefox standard errors popup when I zoom in browser in a page with Morris Chart in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, angularjs, firefox

I am using `morris.js` in an `AngularJS` project to create line charts for a website. When I open it on Firefox and use `command`+`+` to zoom in, Firefox reports a standard error message:

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

I tried Opera, IE and Chrome and they all work well.

When I goes to debug console, it points to different lines every time so I don't know which part of code I should put here. I can provide them on request.

Appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours, I figured out this trick myself. The problem is firefox + morris chart are trying to parse the `xLabels` attribute as a `Datetime`, and lead to a forever-loop.

Just add this to the chart will fix it:

```
parseTime: false
```

Hope it could save some time for someone in the future.